# Free software for making custom themes with full control over desktop elements?

Tags: graphic-design, user-interface, desktop-environment

I want to be able to change/create every aspect of the interface, like: start menu, taskbar, window (or windows explorer)

I'm a big graphics enthusiast and I'm even starting to consider some sort of career as well. Ever since Windows XP I thought themes are made by "big boys" or just Microsoft themeslves, but then it got reasonable that larger audiance can do it as well, but I find it weird there's no free softwares. Or are there?

Is it a lot of a programming thing and if so, where should I start? Or there's an intuitive software somewhere?

Comment: Not answering your question, but addressing another issue you're having: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) (your edit was done using a different account with the same name, so you might wish to get back ownership of your question ;)

Comment: "I need to merge user profiles" should do :) #5 in the contact form's drop-down.